# Applying the Open/closed principle in a method

Tags: c#, design-patterns, solid-principles

Hi I was tasked with refactoring a portion of code in order for it to corespond with the open/closed principle.I managed to do that applying the strategy pattern in two of the methods but in one I do not know how I should proceed.

```
public ProductPriceCalculator(Product product)
{
    this.product = product;
    buyerStrategy = new BuyerStrategy();
    discountStrategy = new DiscountStrategy();
}

public Price CalculatePrice()
{
    price = new Price();

    decimal productPrice = product.BasePrice + 
                           (product.BasePrice * product.Addition);
    decimal TVA = CalculateTVA();
    price.ProductPrice = productPrice*TVA;
    decimal discount = CalculateDiscount(price.ProductPrice);
    price.Discount = price.ProductPrice * discount;
    price.ProductPriceWithDiscount = price.ProductPrice - price.Discount;
    price.TransportPrice = product.Transport.GetTransportPrice();
    price.TotalPrice = price.ProductPriceWithDiscount + price.TransportPrice;

    return price;
}
```

In this case this method initialezes the object by using the methods in the class.As it stands this method is not closed for modification because if at some point I have to add another property to Price I will have to come back here to initialize it.

How can I structure this code right?

Comment: I don't really understand your concern. If your price class gets another property it needs to be initialized in the constructor of Price. If it need a calculated value, you will need to modify the calculation. But somewhere you have to have the code and you will need to modify it. The o/c-principle would be held up by the possibility to just swap out your current price calculator with a new one, probably derived from this one. Make sure you can derive properly from this one.

Comment: @nvoigt Just for the detail, I would say that the possibility to use a derived calculator transparently is more related to the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Open/Closed principle is more about the fact that you can extend calculator features via inheritance without having to modify the code of the original Calculator class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible solution is following:

```
 public class ProductPriceCalculator
 {
    private readonly Product _product;
    private readonly BuyerStrategy _buyerStrategy;
    private readonly DiscountStrategy _discountStrategy;
    private readonly Price _price;

    public ProductPriceCalculator(Product product,BuyerStrategy buyerStrategy,DiscountStrategy discountStrategy,Price price)
    {
        _product = product;
        _buyerStrategy = buyerStrategy;
        _discountStrategy = discountStrategy;
        _price = price;
    }

    public Price CalculatePrice()
    {
        decimal productPrice = _product.BasePrice + (_product.BasePrice * _product.Addition);
        decimal TVA = CalculateTVA();
        decimal discount = CalculateDiscount(productPrice * TVA);
        decimal transportPrice = _product.Transport.GetTransportPrice();

        return _price.CalculatePrice(productPrice*TVA,discount,transportPrice);
    }

    ...

 }

public class Price
{
    ...

    public virtual Price CalculatePrice(decimal productPrice, decimal discount, decimal transportPrice)
    {
        Price price = new Price();

        price.ProductPrice = productPrice;
        price.Discount = ProductPrice * discount;
        price.ProductPriceWithDiscount = ProductPrice - Discount;
        price.TransportPrice = transportPrice;
        price.TotalPrice = ProductPriceWithDiscount + TransportPrice;

        return price;
    }

    ...

}
```

It is good to put dependencies (such as `buyerStrategy`,`discountStrategy`,`price`) in constructor and than fill them via IoC container or something else rather then creating them in constructor themselves.
After introducing `_price` field you can delegate filling price's properties to `Price` class itself. Method `Price.CalculatePrice` can be called as Fabric method for `Price` class.

Comment: +1 I'd do it the same way. Only different is I'd make them interfaces. It lends to testing and extensiblity.

Comment: May be. interface vs inheritance is well known question. but it isn't main point here.

Comment: So using this solution, how would you deal with the addition of extra properties to the Price class?

Comment: In the CalculatePrice using productPrice, discount, transportPrice.
It's obvious!

Answer (score 1):

Bit difficult to say without knowing a little more about the surrounding code - but I would have thought that maybe the [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) could solve this?!  So in your instance perhaps something along these lines :

```
public abstract class BaseProduct
{
    public decimal BasePrice { get; set; }
    public decimal Addition { get; set; }
    public Transport Transport { get; set; }

    public abstract void CalculatePrice(decimal discount);
}

public class Product : BaseProduct
{
    public BasePrice Price { get; set; }

    public Product(BasePrice price)
    {
        this.Price = price;
    }

    public override void CalculatePrice(decimal discount)
    {
        this.Price.CalculatePrice(this.BasePrice, this.Addition, discount);
    }
}

public abstract class BasePrice
{
    public abstract void CalculatePrice(decimal basePrice, decimal additional, decimal discount);
}

public class Price : BasePrice
{
    public decimal ProductPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal Discount { get; set; }
    public decimal ProductPriceWithDiscount { get; set; }
    public decimal TransportPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }

    public override void CalculatePrice(decimal basePrice, decimal additional, decimal discount)
    {
        this.ProductPrice = basePrice + (basePrice * additional);
        this.Discount = this.ProductPrice * discount;
        this.ProductPriceWithDiscount = this.ProductPrice - this.Discount;
        this.TotalPrice = this.ProductPriceWithDiscount + this.TransportPrice;
    }
}
```

Using this method, you can create new concrete implementations of BasePrice as you add new properties and still support the closed principle as you don't need to alter the Calculate logic in the original class, just add new concrete implementations as it changes.  Just to clarify - the *Product* is the Component and the *Price* is the Decorator.

Hopefully I got that right - open to any feedback!  And equally, hope it helps!! :)